# Store pointer address with std::adressof

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

I am probably missing something here.I need to store the pointer address of a newly allocated chunk of memory.

I do this:

```
    void* buffer = _aligned_malloc(4096,4);
    assert(buffer);
    //save its original address:
    void* initialAddress = (void*) std::addressof(buffer );
```

The initialAddress holds different address than that of the buffer.

Only if I assign the buffer pointer I am getting the same address(which is of course the right thing to happen):

```
    initialAddress = buffer;
```

So,why std::addressof(buffer) shows different address?I am using VS2012 to debug.Maybe that's address of the pointer and not the address  of the buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Maybe that's address of the pointer and not the address of the buffer?

That's exactly it. Doing `std::addressof(buffer)` is the same as doing `&buffer` (but they can sometimes mean different things), so you're just getting the address of the `buffer` pointer, which is a `void**`. If you just want a copy of `buffer` instead, do `initialAddress = buffer;`.

Comment: @jrok Forgot to mention that.

Comment: Why then anyone would want to use std::addressof ?

Comment: @MichaelIV Because `operator&` might be overloaded for a certain type. `std::addressof` avoids that overload.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing address pointed to by `buffer` and address of `buffer` itself. They are different.